# trick to increase only font size

Tags: html, css, svg, fonts, rect

I have a chart shown on the webpage. I want to increase the font size without increasing the row size. With the API if i want to increase the font size it increase the row size.

Demo link: https://plnkr.co/edit/UGlDe2XjfhLw4tlTwEyB?p=preview
In the above demo i want to increase the font size of the text shown inside the rows(P1 Data, P3 Data).

Generated code:
[image]

I tried with below css code which is not working:

```
     #chart1 svg rect {
     font :9px;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few mistakes here:

1. its `font-size` not `font`
2. Try targeting the `text` element not the `rect` figure

> Try this:

```
#chart1 svg text {
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

Hope it helps. If not please comment so i can help you further